# fabric-js textBakgroundColor not covering whole text when changing object property

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, fabricjs

I am using [fabric-js](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Textbox.html) for creating templates on canvas. but facing a wired issue.

I have added a `Textbox` object to canvas, when i am trying to change *fontFamily* and *fontWeight* of `Textbox`, sometimes the textBackgroundColor not cover the whole text.

[image]

I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2yL3mvrx/10/) to showcase this issue.

### Steps to reproduce:

- Select textbox object, change fontFamily from `Merriweather` to `Lato`
- Then change fontWeight from `normal` to `bold`

> **Note:** it is happening for specific fonts like `Merriweather` not for
>   all, Also sometimes it works but not everytime.

Comment: This has been fixed in new version I guess, [check](https://jsfiddle.net/2yL3mvrx/11/)

Comment: @Durga It is not fixed, i am using latest version `2.0.0-rc.4`

Comment: Check the fiddle I posted

Comment: i checked it, it is not working, try to change the fontFamily you can see the issue.

Comment: I have answered this question here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77041881/14241577

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen when the fonts are not properly loaded.
The fabricJs request the font bold, that is not ready, not even the regular one is ready, and render with a fallback.
When the font is ready, the font measurement is already done, and is wrong.

You have to properly load the fonts with a font loader.
Check for fontFaceObeserver, is really easy to use.

In the snippet below i used just a very hacky setTimeout and 2 paragraph to force the browser to load the font in advance.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
setTimeout(function() {
text = new fabric.Textbox("Click here twice to edit", {
  width: 300,
  fontSize: 25,
  fontFamily: 'Merriweather',
  textAlign: 'center',
  textBackgroundColor : '#000',
  fill: '#ffc107',
});
canvas.add(text);

window.toggleBoldText = function() {
  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if(obj){
    if (obj.get('fontWeight') == 'normal'){
      obj.set('fontWeight', 'bold');
    }else{
      obj.set('fontWeight', 'normal');
    }
   canvas.renderAll();
  }else{
    alert("select text object to add font weight");
  }
}

window.toggleFontFamily = function() {
  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if(obj){
   if (obj.get('fontFamily') == 'Merriweather'){
      obj.set('fontFamily', 'Lato');
    }else{
      obj.set('fontFamily', 'Merriweather');
    }
    canvas.renderAll();
  }else{
    alert("select text object to add font family");
  }  
}

}, 3000);
```

```css
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather%7CLato);

.canvas-container {
  border: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.js"></script>
<button onclick="toggleFontFamily()">toggle font family</button>
<button onclick="toggleBoldText()">toggle bold</button>
<span style="font-family: Merriweather; font-weight: bold;">Merri bold</span><span style="font-family: Merriweather; font-weight: normal;">Merri normal</span>
<canvas width="500" height="300" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issues, but i created the select element with options, where user can picked the font what he needed. Before i dont use font style on select options but after a few hours of googling i realize that can just add that fonts to  list and the fonts will be downloaded.

after that fabricjs work great