# Text outside bounding box in fabric js

Tags: canvas, fonts, fabricjs, bounding-box, font-family

I am using fabric js for the annotations. I am facing an issue while adding text of specific font family. When I add text, it goes outside the bounding box and that's why the text which is outside is removed. How can I fix text inside the bounding box?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edit: here's how I solved it.

```
        canvas.getObjects().forEach(function(object) {
                
                if(object.type=='i-text'){
                    object.set("width", object.width * 1.3)
```

...

Previous answer:
Did you solve it? Facing the same issue.[bounding box issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnpc6.png)

This is how it is reproduced in my case:

1. save canvas as JSON
2. The itext element is given width
3. Load the JSON
4. Change the itext element font.
5. The new font is bigger so the text goes outside bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

After font load use this

```
await loadFontsInCanvas(canvas, fontData);
    
fabric.util.clearFabricFontCache();
canvas.getObjects()?.forEach((object) => {
  if (object?.Type === 'text') {
    handleTextOverflow(object);
  }
});
canvas.renderAll();

function handleTextOverflow(textbox) {
  const textWidth = textbox.calcTextWidth();
  const textHeight = textbox.calcTextHeight();
  textbox.set({
    width: textWidth,
    height: textHeight,
  });
}
```

So what it will do is clear the cache of fonts thats why it was calculating the wrong box size